# Extracting specific bits from an integer and saving them into a string in C?

Tags: c, string, integer, save, bit

I'm having trouble with extracting specific bits from a 32-bit long integer and saving those specific bits into a string.

To better explain my problem, I'll explain it like this:

Okay, let's say I have this integer:

```html
01010101010101010101000011010100
```

I want to extract (going from MSB to LSB) from the 2nd (included) to the 21th bit (included).

So I can simply create a mask that will keep only the 20 bits I want and zero all others.

```html
Integer: 01010101010101010101000011010100
Mask:    01111111111111111111100000000000

New integer = Integer & Mask = 01010101010101010101000000000000
```

After that, I have no idea, how to save those 20 bits to a string.

Okay, now lets say we have a char array that can hold 100 characters.

I then need to copy those 20 bits from the integer into the char array so that only those 20 bits are displayed as text. This is how it should be:

```html
printf("Text: %s", string); -> "Text: 10101010101010101010"
```

I hope I explained it well enough. If you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: Please don't count bits from the left. The `0th` bit is the most righthand bit as we generally write it, the least significant. So your mask `01111111111111111111100000000000` is bits 11 to 30. As to the question, you can convert that to a string by shifting bits one by one. I am sure there has been a similar question.

Comment: Is there any reason to save it as an ASCII binary string?  Why not save it as binary and write a function to print it as an ASCII binary string? That way, `Integer & Mask` is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long long extractbits(unsigned long long data, unsigned start, unsigned end)
{
    unsigned long long mask;
    if(start > end)
    {
        unsigned tmp = start;
        end = start;
        start = tmp;
    }
    mask = (end == sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8 - 1) ? ~0ULL : (1ULL << (end + 1))) - 1;
    return ((data & mask) >> start);
}

char *to_string(char *buff, unsigned long long data)
{
    char *cptr = buff;
    char *sptr = buff;
    while(data)
    {
        *cptr++ = (data & 1) ? '1' : '0';
        data >>= 1;
    }
    *cptr-- = 0;
    while(cptr > buff)
    {
        char tmp = *cptr;
        *cptr-- = *buff;
        *buff++ = tmp;
    }
    return sptr;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[25];
    printf("%s\n", to_string(buff, extractbits(0b11100011100011100011ULL, 4, 17)));

    return 0;
}
```